# How can I prove that $\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$ is decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove that $\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$ is decreasing? I've tried subtracting subsequent terms but without success. No derivative arguments please.

Comment: @jacer21 As I mentioned, no derivative arguments please

Comment: Perhaps you should explain the context a little better when you want to exclude some arguments.  For example, would using logarithms have been acceptable here?  Excluding derivatives doesn't explicitly exclude taking a logarithm, but it suggests you have some narrow agenda that might be better explained up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bernoulli's inequality
$$1+(n+1)(a-1)\leq a^{n+1}$$

With $$a=\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}$$